# css not displaying with absolute paths after .htaccess re_writes

Tags: html, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm faced with the problem of CSS  not being displayed after using the mod_rewrite in .htaccess, heres the problem:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks  
RewriteEngine On  
RewriteRule ^css/(.*)$ Templates/Testing/html/css/$1 [QSA]
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d  
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f  

RewriteRule ^.*$ ./index.php
```

CSS is located in:

> Templates/{TemplateName}/html/css/

TemplateName in this case being Testing.. But on my view source, it's just an infiniate loop to whatever I have in my

```
 <link href="" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

I've tried making virtual directorys to remap a virtual directory to a physical directory, but this has no luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding `L` flag in both the rules:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks  

RewriteEngine On  
RewriteRule ^(css/.+)$ Templates/Testing/html/$1 [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d  
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f  
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

Comment: Works like a charm, the problem is.. After i've got more than 2 parameters in my URL /work/work/stopsworking, the CSS doesn't display?